# Matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation using pcolormesh

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

Python 3.5, windows 10 Pro.

I'm trying to continuously plot an 8x8 array of pixels (for the sake of the question I'll just use random data, but in the real thing I'm reading from a serial port).

I can do it using a while loop, but I need to switch over to matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation and I can't get it to work. I've tried looking at the help files and tried to follow examples from matplotlib.org [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/index.html), but I've not been able to follow it.

Can someone help me figure out how to continuously plot an 8x8 array of pixels using FuncAnimation and pcolormesh? Here is what I've got so far:

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

plt.close('all')

y = sp.rand(64).reshape([8,8])

def do_something():
    y = sp.rand(64).reshape([8,8])
    fig_plot.set_data(y)
    return fig_plot,

fig1 = plt.figure(1,facecolor = 'w')
plt.clf()

fig_plot = plt.pcolormesh(y)

fig_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1,do_something)    
plt.show()
```

If you want to see the while loop code, just so you know exactly what I'm trying to reproduce, see below.

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
while True:
    y = sp.rand(64).reshape([8,8])
    plt.pcolormesh(y)
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(.000001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution using imshow instead of pcolormesh. In case anyone else is struggling with the same issues I had, I've posted the working code below.

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

Hz = sp.rand(64).reshape([8,8])  # initalize with random data

fig = plt.figure(1,facecolor='w')

ax = plt.axes()
im = ax.imshow(Hz)
im.set_data(sp.zeros(Hz.shape))

def update_data(n):
    Hz = sp.rand(64).reshape([8,8])  # More random data
    im.set_data(Hz)
    return

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_data, interval = 10, blit = False, repeat = False)
fig.show()
```